# Passing function as callback without argument - need help to understand it

Tags: javascript

I've seen a code sample like that in some tutorial:

```
getSomething(function onSomething(name) {
  return renderSomething(name);
});
```

And that it is equal to the following:

```
getSomething(renderSomething);
```

I'm a newbie, and never seen anything like this before. I can't really understand how the above can be the same(without parameter on the `renderSomething()`).
I've tried to recreate something similar to the above code to better understand it and kind of failed. I'm showing you what I've tried and hopefully you can explain to me why the above is equivalent and the below two questions that came up.

Can you please explain to me:

1. Why parameter `name` is undefined?
2. How come the `console.log('a')` is printed before the `console.log('c')`?

```js
var name = 'alex';
console.log('start');

function print(cb) {
  console.log('a');
  cb();
}

function renderName(name) {
  console.log('b');
  console.log(name);
}

print(function onPrint(name) {
  console.log('name: ', name);
  console.log('c');
  return renderName(name);
});
```

Comment: Thats because you have not passed anything to the callback in the print function

Comment: I've tried that, but probably did it kind of wrong, I guess. I've tried to pass it like that and it gave me an error: `function print(cb) {
      console.log('a');
      cb(a);
    }`

Comment: `a` is not a variable, so you need to add the quotes.

Comment: Be careful with parameter names that equal global properties. Like `name` or `window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand how those two statements are equivalent, you really need to look inside of the function and also to reflect on why we use callbacks in the first place. It's also important to understand the difference between function declarations (`function getFullName`), invocations (`getFullName()`) and references (`getFullName`).

We use callbacks to react to something that might happen later, usually the result of whatever has happened is of interest to us. So we create callbacks that receive that result.

Imagine you have a function `getFullName`, if it was synchronous you would just call it like this:

```
const fullName = getFullName('John', 'Doe');
```

And inside the function might simply be:

```
function getFullName(firstName, lastName) {
    return firstName + ' ' + lastName;
}
```

But for some reason, this function is asynchronous, so you don't get the result directly, so we use a callback to get notified when the name is ready to use:

```
function getFullName(firstName, lastName, callback) {
    // Do something that takes time, then with the result of that
    callback(firstName + ' ' + lastName);
}
```

Now when we call this function, it looks like this:

```
getFullName('John', 'Doe', function (fullName) {
    console.log(fullName);
});
```

So the `getFullName` function, will invoke our callback and pass it the value it created. Since your function takes 1 argument, the fullName will be in that argument, no matter what we name that argument. So we can replace our callback (that we've created as an anonymous function) with any other function that takes one argument, such as console.log, like this:

```
getFullName('John', 'Doe', console.log)
```

In both these cases, we're sending in a function reference to `getFullName`, in the first case it's a reference from a function we've just created, in the second it's a reference to a function in the global scope.

You could equally do this:

```
const myCallback = function(fullName) {
   console.log(fullName);
}

getFullName('John', 'Doe', myCallback);
```

Note how this is different from doing something like this:

```
getFullName('John', 'Doe', myCallback()); <-- function invocation!
```

Here, because we are invoking/calling the function, it will execute, and the result of that will be passed as the third argument to `getFullName`, which isn't what we wanted.

Reading up on first class functions might give you more insight!

As others have mentioned, but for completion, in your example, you never pass some result to your callback, in this case you could pass the variable `name` or something else to simulate the result being created. And by flipping the order in which you call console.log and `cb(name)` your logs should make sense.
What you return from your callback function will never really be used, at least not in our example.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the parameter to `cb` in `print` function

```js
var name = 'alex';
console.log('start');

function print(cb) {
  console.log('a');
  return cb(name);
}

function renderName(name) {
  console.log('b');
  console.log(name);
}

print(function onPrint(name) {
  console.log('name: ', name);
  console.log('c');
  return renderName(name);
});
```

Comment: No, there is no need to return in the callback or in the print function.

Answer (score 1):

As to your questions:

> Why parameter `name` is undefined?

Because you didn't pass an argument when you called `cb()`. It would have worked if for instance you had done `cb("John")`.

> How come the `console.log('a')` is printed before the `console.log('c')`?

Because that is the very first thing that the `print` function does. It only calls your callback with `cb()` *after* having done that.